# Rails subscription model with promo code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subscription

Currently here is my User -> Subscription Model

```
# User Model
has_many :subscriptions

# Subscription Model
belongs_to :user
```

I am wanting to add in the ability for a user to enter in a promo code and have access to the application via the subscription that is tied to the promo code entered. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think we need more information. How is a promo code used? Are there many promo codes? Can they be reused?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I left out some info... Promo codes are used to associate the right subscription to the user. Yes there can be many promo codes and yes they can be re-used.

Comment: Are you describing a :through relationship here? So, for example, a user has many subscriptions through a promo code? Is this what you're looking for? `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, where a user can have multiple  subscriptions and a subscription can have many users. AdamT is right with a :through model, where the :through model is :promo_code. This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) gives a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the help! I have my has_and_belongs_to_many  associations setup between subscriptions and users. My original plan was to simply just associate promo codes to subscriptions and just add the subscription to the user upon entering a valid promo code.